# By clicking the button to accept cookies back null

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I'm trying to accept a cookie but it always returns null. As if it didn't exist on that page.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')

const main = async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
  });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://cloud.ibm.com/login')
  await page.waitFor('body > div:nth-child(16) > div.mainContent > div > div:nth-child(2) > div.pdynamicbutton > a.call')
  await page.click('body > div:nth-child(16) > div.mainContent > div > div:nth-child(2) > div.pdynamicbutton > a.call')

}

main()
```

`"puppeteer": "^5.2.1"`

Comment: The documentation for [page.onClick](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v3.0.4&show=api-pageclickselector-options) says it resolves with `undefined`. Are you by any chance confusing null with undefined? Sounds like you're getting the right behavior

Comment: Also, a quick recommendation for testing, add `data-test-id="accept-cookie` to your button/anchor so that you don't have to do that complex css selector and instead can do a simple `await page.click('[data-test-id="accept-cookie"]');`

Comment: there is only the element when I click on inspect